# Node Reference retrieve Field

Tags: views, nodes

I'm using Views RSS to generate custom RSS feed which includes georss

I have to content types `Shops` and `Events` I can get the location fine from `Shops` because it has dedicated location field, but `Events` uses `Node Reference` to generate drop down menu of all `Shops` and has no location field.

How can I access the location of the referenced `Shop` from the `View`? I understand I have to create a relationship, but I'm not really sure where to start.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View of nodes where content type = Event.

Add a relationship to nodes referenced via the Shops field.

Add a field for Location using the Shops relationship.